# Python 2.7.10 class object list

Tags: python, python-2.7, list, object, dictionary

Is it possibly to make 'self.elo' object a list (or maybe vector?), which has every single data point on it.

```
class Joukkue:
    def __init__(self, name, games, elo):
        self.name = name
        self.games = games
        self.elo = elo
```

I'm currently just changing the values into new ones, but I would like to see the development of teams rating(elo) and maybe visualize it aswell. This is how I do this currently:

```
lista = {}
lista[ID1].elo = a
lista[ID2].elo = b
```

This is just part of my code and I can post the whole .py file if needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly you want to make self.elo a list. I believe this is possible this way:

```
self.elo = [items, in, here]
```

Comment: Ok it was this easy. Thanks!

Comment: No problem, Happy to help!